# Categorizing continuous response variables: good or bad?

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, ordinal-data, continuous-data, ordered-logit

I have two continuous variables that I wanted to model on 5 explanatory variables. When I did, using linear regression (and mixed-effects linear regression), none of the variables were statistically significant in both models according to LR test (or Wald test). Then I categorized both response variables into 4 categories and I chose the thresholds based on my knowledge of the nature of them (not any statistical measure e.g. median) and used mixed effect ordered logit (aka mixed-effect cumulative link models) and all the variables are statistically significant in a reasonable way. Is anything wrong with the logic of my approach? How can I justify this categorization in my paper?

Comment: Any outliers that might have been effectively trimmed by the binning?

Comment: Yes, I think there are less than 10 outliers (among 450 total observations) that are trimmed.

Comment: Might consider seeing what happens if you are more aggressive with trimming. Or try a reasonable transform (log, sqrt)

Comment: I just tried and ^0.125 works perfectly. Thank you very much for your comment. What do you recommend to mention in the paper for justification?

Comment: It’s a tricky situation you have yourself in. You might consider diving deep and seeing exactly which data points get thrown out when the model shifts from not significant to significant. Perhaps one data point is really throwing off the model but the outlier detection method is only loosely correlated with finding it. Another option is to try a log transform first and then a standard outlier removal method after. That would be easier to justify I would think.

Comment: I have around 30% zeros in the continuous variable. How can I do a log transformation? I added 10^-9 to all values so log works, but I think it is not a good approach, since a little change in this epsilon (e.g. 10^-8) leads to prominent changes in the log values. How should I do the log transformation that keeps the results interpretable, too?

Comment: Some folks add a one before the log xform. If the values range between 0-1 you can also use sqrt. As far as interpreting, you can use the xform to make the distribution fit the assumptions of the statistical model better. If after the model finds a reliable difference, then that’s enough evidence to justify reporting the difference, and so for your effect size measures you could go back to the untransformed scale and report on that scale.